# Проблемы с отображением картинок в UITableViewCell

Tags: swift

При первом запуске приложения картинки увеличиваются, но после свайпа вниз или поиска все нормально

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  print(indexPath.row)
  let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
  let track = searchResponse?.results[indexPath.row]
  cell.videoTitlesLabel.text = track?.collectionName
  if let link = track?.artworkUrl60 {
    NetworkService.downloadedImage(link: link, completion: {
      (image) in
      if image != nil {
        print("set image \(indexPath.row)")
      }
      cell.videoImageView.image = image
    })
  }
  return cell
}
```

Comment: Как Вы задаёте высоту строк в таблице? Как Вы задаёте размер `videoImageView`?

Comment: Забыл задать высоту, спасибо